# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 in adonis 5 docker mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, adonis.js

I'm using Adonis 5 and Mysql database , after following some tutorials i added this code to connect mysql. but it shows me "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" error. Here is my code below:

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

# RUN apk add --no-cache git

COPY . /home/node/app/

RUN chown -R node:node /home/node

RUN npm install

USER node

EXPOSE 3333

ENTRYPOINT ["node","ace","serve","--watch"]
```

my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# For more information: https://github.com/julien-r44/adonis-sail
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
   image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
   container_name: mysql
   expose:
     - "3307"
  ports:
     - '${MYSQL_PORT:-3307}:3306'
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: '${MYSQL_DB_NAME:?err}'
    MYSQL_USER: '${MYSQL_USER:?err}'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD?:err}'
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
  volumes:
    - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
  networks:
   - sail

phpmyadmin:
  image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin'
  links:
     - 'mysql:mysql'
  ports:
     - 8080:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: "${MYSQL_USER}"
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    PMA_HOST: mysql
  networks:
   - sail
app:
 links:
   - mysql
 build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
 volumes:
  - .:/home/node/app
  - /home/node/app/node_modules
 ports:
  - 3333:3333
 depends_on:
  - mysql
  - phpmyadmin
networks:
 sail:
  driver: bridge

volumes:
 sailmysql:
  driver: "local"
```

My `.env` file:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=3333
APP_URL=http://${HOST}:${PORT}
NODE_ENV=development
APP_KEY=wH94pOFV47NO0dJtE_S6-TDRgcjgZXGM
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
CACHE_VIEWS=false
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_USER=adonis
MYSQL_PASSWORD=adonis
MYSQL_DB_NAME=social
```

Error:
[it shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VMOR.png)

What is my mistake?

Comment: What is the text form of the logs from the mysql container?

Comment: [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.28-1.2.7-server

[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.28-1.2.7-server

Answer (score 2):

Change from `MYSQL_HOST=localhost` to `MYSQL_HOST=mysql`

When your app is running inside a docker container, `localhost` points no longer to your laptop (or server) but to the container itself.

As each service is running in separated containers when one application is trying to access the database service you cannot use `localhost`. As `localhost` points to that container, and the database is not installed there.

You should use the container name instead `localhost` when specificying connection urls.

You can also check [Docker Compose network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) documentation for detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: from logical perspective you are 100% correect but this didn't solve the problem